# Connect to telnet-ssl in php

Tags: php, ssl, telnet

I need a authentication against telnet server:

there is a server I can connect using telnet-ssl

```
telnet-ssl -8 server port
```

typing in username and password.
With telnet-ssl it works.  But when I tried

```
fsockopen("ssl://server",port,..);
```

it ends with:
SSL: crypto enabling timeout
(time out is set to 5 but it can be 50 and it's still same error)

I really don't know what to do..

Comment: Are you sure you can connect to that telnet server from the server, looks like a firewall problem to me

Comment: I'm testing it on my local machine.. telnet-ssl works, fsockopen doesn't